# Equations for `someFunction' have different numbers of arguments

Tags: haskell

I'm using in order to practice/learn Haskell. I'm having trouble understanding why a given situation works on my example local code, and doesn't work on CodeWars.

On codewars:

```
module Codewars.Kata.Negative where

makeNegative :: (Num a) => a -> a
makeNegative x = x + x
makeNegative = error "todo: makeNegative"
```

This gives me:

```
Codewars/Kata/Negative.hs:4:1:
    Equations for `makeNegative' have different numbers of arguments
      Codewars/Kata/Negative.hs:4:1-22
      Codewars/Kata/Negative.hs:5:1-41
```

But when I test it locally:

```
import Data.List
import System.IO

example :: (Num a) => a -> a
example x = x + x
main = do
  print (example(3))
```

It returns 6 properly. I can't even try to solve the problem because the compiler complains about the arguments. I *kinda* got it that Num is a "typeclass", but I don't get how that works differently on codewars. I guess its because of that "where" clause there.

Comment: Because you have an extra definition. remove `makeNegative = error "todo: makeNegative"`

Comment: If you intend the 2nd clause as some sort of placeholder, it still needs to have one (possibly dummy) argument just like the first clause. Like: `makeNegative _ = error "todo: makeNegative"`. Otherwise the 2nd clause contradicts the type signature. But even like that, it is unreachable as is, and so the compiler will complain in another fashion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in your definition of `makeNegative`. Notice there's three lines of the definition:

```
makeNegative :: (Num a) => a -> a
makeNegative x = x + x
makeNegative = error "todo: makeNegative"
```

The first is the type signature, followed by two definitions. Oftentimes multiple definitions are provided when pattern matching on arguments and handling different cases; however in this case the pattern match will never fail; so the `error` line will never run.

Regardless of the fact that it will never be run; Haskell still requires that all implementations of a function have the same number of bound arguments, `makeNegative x =` binds one argument (namely `x`); but the second definition `makeNegative =` doesn't bind any arguments. In this case it looks like it's a placeholder definition so you can just delete the line with `error` and it should work.

Your `example` test only has a single definition, so it doesn't run into this issue.